# Make entire python terminal text a specific color?

Tags: python, terminal, colors

I want to make it so that everything printed and inputted into the python terminal is a specific color like purple or green. Just like in C#, when you use the Console.ForegroundColor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the colorama module

```
import colorama
print(coloroma.Fore.RED + 'This text is red in color')
```

The output will be red in color!

Comment: I meant like everything in the terminal prints red, without having to print using colorama

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ANSI escape codes](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/user-guide/materials/ansi-escape-codes/) a little something like this:

```py
red = "\x1b[32m"
color_off = "\x1b[0m"

print(f"{red}some text in red color{color_off}")
```

But why code everything from scratch? You can find several good Python package options that can solve your problem. In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package. [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) is lightweight and less verbose. Simply install the package with `pip install colorist` and type:

```py
from colorist import red

red("some text in red color")
```

[image: some text in red color]

Sometimes you may want a little more control over the terminal style, so you can also do this:

```py
from colorist import Color

print(f"Only {Color.CYAN}this part{Color.OFF} is in colour")
```

Note that it's good practice to turn off the colour. Otherwise, any color or styling may spill over and into other terminal messages.

[image: Only this part is in colour]